# Como puedo llenar la columna de una tabla con la misma imagen dentro de un ciclo?(BLOB y LOOP es posible?)

Tags: sql, plsql

Tengo una duda. como se podría insertar a través de un ciclo la misma imagen de forma masiva? lo otro es que debe ser en una tabla que tiene muchas columnas, pero yo solo quiero llenar la columna "foto " de la tabla producto, por lo que la sentencia "INSERT INTO" no me serviría ya que me tira un error de que los valores no son suficientes :/  en pocas palabras...existe una forma de llenar solo esa columna con la misma imagen ?﻿

este es mi codigo:

ALTER TABLE PRODUCTO ADD FOTO BLOB DEFAULT EMPTY_BLOB();

DECLARE

```
V_BLOB BLOB;
V_BFILE BFILE;



V_MINIMO NUMBER(8):=0;
V_MAXIMO NUMBER(8):=0;
```

BEGIN

```
SELECT MIN(CODPRODUCTO),MAX(CODPRODUCTO)
INTO V_MINIMO,V_MAXIMO
FROM PRODUCTO;

FOR i IN V_MINIMO..V_MAXIMO LOOP





INSERT INTO PRODUCTO 
VALUES (EMPTY_BLOB()) RETURNING FOTO INTO V_BLOB;

V_BFILE:= BFILENAME('ORACLECLRDIR',i||'.PNG');
DBMS_LOB.OPEN(V_BFILE,DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);
DBMS_LOB.LOADFROMFILE(V_BLOB,V_BFILE,DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(V_BFILE));
DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(V_BFILE);

COMMIT;
END LOOP;
```

END;

como podran observar a la tabla producto tuve que agregarle la columna que almacenara las imagenes 1,2,3,4...hasta que llegue al ultimo id(segun la variable maxima) pero al utilizar la sentencia "INSERT INTO" el compilador me arroja un error de que "no hay valores suficientes" ya que la tabla tiene muchas columnas y yo solo quiero actualizar la columna "FOTO". quedo atento !!

Comment: Haz un insert para insertar la imagen, luego haces un update sin where usando la imagen que insertaste. Asi ya no haces stores procedures.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! La sentencia insert into si funciona, la estas usando incorrectamente. Vos podes aclarar que campos queres llenar y que no.

Comment: pero como puedo realizar dicho insert si al realizarlo me dice que no hay suficientes valores??? solo quiero actualizar una sola columna (-_-')